# Product Image Size In Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, adobe-xd

what is the best practice to set image size for banners and products in E-Commerce/Shopping android application? and what are the ideal image sizes for the product and banners so that it can be responsive for all screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are different ways you can handle this:

1. Use a high-resolution image file put it into `drawable-nodpi` and resize that based on your screen density. (I recommend using Glide, but Bitmap and BitmapFactory consist of methods handling resizing and loading bitmaps)

   - Pro: A single image file can be easily scaled
   - Con: It can lead to OutOfMemory if not handled correctly.

---

2. Put your images into different density buckets [MORE INFO](https://medium.com/@ramtintoosi/android-dp-fully-explained-46052e5b6aa). The image files should be based on common pixel densities that phones are manufactured base on e.g. Full-HD (1080x1920) or HD resolution.

   - Pro: It's less work for OS and even your own coding
   - Con: It's more work to design image files